# How do a foreach on an object with integer keys?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm loading a json file where there's an object `data`, which has properties that are *only integers*.

They begin with `1000` then increment until `9999`. Everything is ok. The problem comes with the properties `10000` and higher. When I load the file using `json_decode(file_get_contents('myjsonfile'))`, if I try to do a `foreach` loop I have all the properties that begin with `1000` first, so this includes all the properties `10000` then I have other ones (`2000`, `3000`, and so on).

The actual problem is that *I need to keep the keys* (because the properties are objects that sometimes contain link to keys of the "base" `data` object).

How can you make a working `foreach` loop with keys ordered asc?

Comment: So you are sorting array keys as strings. Sort it as integers, so 10000 comes after 9999.

Comment: I dont want to sort it, it just want to make a foreach on it.

Comment: Are you using `foreach($array as $key => $value)` or `foreach($array as $value){ $index++ }`?

Comment: That's what I'm saying: if I do a `foreach($array as $key => $value)` I begin with 1000, 1001, then 10001, 10002, then 2000, 2001. I want to have: 1000, 1001, 2000, 2001, then 10001, 10002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using a temporary table to sort key with `SORT_NATURAL` then foreach on it:

```
$tmp=array();
foreach ($obj as $key=>$item) {
    $tmp[$key]=$item;
}
$tmp=(array_keys($tmp));
sort($tmp, SORT_NATURAL);
foreach ($tmp as $key) {
    $item=$obj->$key;
    /* ... my other code, with a good iteration ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON array keys are strings, that's why you get array sorted automatically.

Use `ksort` function first:

```
$array = (array) json_decode(json_encode(array("3000" => "Third", "10000" => "Fourth", "2000" => 'Second', "1000" => 'First')));

ksort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    var_dump($k, $v); echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: You could write the full JSON string in json_decode() so you dont go through json_encode(), which might change the result.

Comment: @OlivierPons You do not provided any JSON string, so I created you in ugly useless way. You can replace it with your JSON array.